# Parent child directory same name , move files to parent directory

Tags: bash, files, find, python, move

I need a way to search directories for child directories with the same name and then move all files in the child directory to the parent.
Thus from
`/recup-dir1/recup-dir1/files to /recup-dir1/files.`
The child directories can be left empty because i can use something like
`find . -type -d -empty -delete`
to delete all empty dirs

So the problem is i have no idea in which directories there are the child directories with the same name and in which there are not.

In pseudo code i need something like this.

```
While more directories are unchecked
get name-x of  next dir
   enter dir  
   If name-x/name-x exist
   move all files in name-x/name-x to name-x
   mark dir as done
next
```

My best guess is to create a little python script to make a list of all directories which have a child with the same name and loop this list throug a command like
`find something something -exec mv`

Maybe this could be done with bash scripting or another solution exists. Like some rsync command, however since i created this mess probably with rsync i don't think that will be the solution.

Edit:  here is an actual part of the tree output:
The toplevel dirs are inside  /mnt/external-disk/tst-backup
There are no sub-dirs on lower levels.

```
│   └── recup_dir.1
├── recup_dir.10
│   └── recup_dir.10
├── recup_dir.100
│   └── recup_dir.100
├── recup_dir.102
│   └── recup_dir.102
└── recup_dir.1020
    └── recup_dir.1020
```

Comment: I'd think about using the `tree -d` command - with extra parameters; for example is an XML file useful?

Comment: Thanks @JeremyBoden.
I looked into the three manpage an constructed these commands:
`$ tree -d -P recup.dir* --prune -o /home/tom/tmp-backup2.json -J`
and 
`$ tree -d -P recup.dir* --prune -o /home/tom/tmp-backup2.xml -X`
Next step is editing those files to remove all unaffected directories en somehow loop through one of them an start moving the files.

Comment: ... BTW, 2 questions: **1)** once you have moved file from `/path/to/dirname/**/dirname/` to`/path/to/dirname`, why do you want to do with the emptied subdirectory `/path/to/dirname/**/dirname/` ? **2)** what if among moved files some have names that are identical to files in the destination dir ? What to do ?

Comment: Hi @Cbhihe thanks for the welcome.
 My answer to your questions:
 Yes i will post the answer when i have a solution
1) All empty dirs may deleted or moved to /dev/null.

Comment: To slow to edit so here is the full comment: 
 Hi @Cbhihe thanks for the welcome.
 My answer to your questions:
 Yes i will post the answer when i have a solution (i have not at the moment )
1) All empty dirs may deleted or moved to /dev/null.
2) If a file with the same name exists then the moved file should be renamed with an extra number on the the end.  'file_a.txt exists so new name is file_a-1.txt'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
for dir in **/*(NDodoN/e['[[ $REPLY:t = $REPLY:h:t ]]']); do
  contents=($dir/*(NDoN))
  (( $#contents == 0 )) ||
    mv -- $contents $dir:h/ &&
    rmdir -- $dir
done
```

Where:

- `**/*(qualifiers)` recursive globbing with glob qualifiers
- `N`: nullglob: don't complain if there's no match
- `D`: dotglob: include hidden files
- `od`: order depth first (leaves before the branches they're on).
- `oN`: don't bother with ordering the list of files otherwise.
- `/`: restrict to files of type directory.
- `e['expression']`: restrict to files for which the `expression` code returns true (inside which the current file path is stored in `$REPLY`).
- `$REPLY:t`: tail (basename) of the file
- `$REPLY:h:t`: tail of the head (dirname) of the files)

With `bash` 4.4+ and GNU `find` or the `find` or most BSDs, you could do something similar with:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
readarray -td '' dirs < <(
  LC_ALL=C find . -depth -regex '.*\(/[^/]*\)\1' -type d -print0
)
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  contents=("$d"/*)
  (( ${#contents[@]} == 0 )) ||
    mv -- "${contents[@]}" "${d%/*}/" &&
    rmdir -- "$d"
done
```

This time using a regular expression to match the `./path/to/dir/dir` files using basic regular expression back-references.

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane.
Those are both very compact solutions.  The zsh one is a bit hard to read for me but  your explanation is very helpful.  I go test these solutions later today.

Comment: Both the bash as the zsh version do work. 
However bc I do not quite understand  both bash language i will be very carefull to use these.
I saved both solutions as a zsh or bash script and put some echo statements in to track progress.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, based on GNU `find` v4.8.0 and Bash v5.1.8

#### Part 1: Parse directory tree + detect sub-dir name dupes

Assume that a certain directory in your tree has the following structure:

```
./
|__test1/
     |__dirname with space
     |           |__test2
     |                |__ test2
     |__dirname **
     |       |__test1
     |
     |__reboot
     |     |__test1
     | 
     |__test2/
          |__test3/
               |__test2/
                    |__test1/
                         |__test1/
```

*(Strange directory names are there to demonstrate code safety.)*

You see that some sub-directories (subdirs) are repeated in different ways. Some are repeated multiple times, not just once (e.g. `test1`), one is not repeated (`test3`), and they can be repeated either as parent and child or separated by an arbitrary number of intermediate subdirs.

The code below reveals subdir name dupes in a directory structure in a detailed way.

- it parses the file tree for the subdir structure starting from `$PWD`
- it finds dupes for each components of any subdir path of 2 or more levels, not counting the root level which is `$PWD`. In my experiment, the longest subdir path is:
  `./test1/test2/test1/test3/test2/test1/test1`
- it prints the first subdir dupe found at each subdir level, starting from the leaf, i.e. reading the subdir path right to left.
- printing is redirected toward a file, in reverse order so the longest subdir path is shown first. Two consecutive semicolons separates the path components (to the left of the ";;"), from first dupe (to the right of ";;") found according to the previous bullet.

[Code]

```
$ find ./* -type d -exec bash -c 'set -o noglob; IFS="/" subdir=($(printf "%s " "$1")); dirlevels=$((${#subdir[@]}-1)); dupe="$(awk '\''!($1 in sd) {sd[$1];next} {print $1}'\'' < <(printf "%s\n" ${subdir[@]:1}))";[ $dirlevels -ge 2 ] && [ ! -z "$dupe"  ] && (printf "%s/" "${subdir[@]:1}";printf " ;; %s\n" "$(tail -n 1 < <(printf "%s\n" "$dupe"))";)' shellexec {} \; | tac >| tmp.data

$ cat -n  tmp.data

1 test1/reboot/test1/ ;; test1
2 test1/dirname with space/test2/test2/ ;; test2
3 test1/test2/test1/test3/test2/test1/test1/ ;; test1
4 test1/test2/test1/test3/test2/test1/ ;; test1
5 test1/test2/test1/test3/test2/ ;; test2
6 test1/test2/test1/test3/ ;; test1
7 test1/test2/test1/ ;; test1
8 test1/dirname **/test1/ ;; test1
```

#### Part 2:  Processing of subdir name dupes; moving contents

Processing takes place in the order displayed in `tmp.data`.

- on `tmp.data`'s first line, the first name dupe on the path `./test1/test2/test1/test3/test2/test1/test1` is `test1`. We can transfer its contents to the left most subdir level with the same name: `./test1/`
- once the contents have been moved with no clobbering of existing files at destination, the right most subdir level `test1` is deleted.
- we go on to line 2 of `tmp.data` and repeat the above steps.
- etc until all lines in `tmp.data` have been consumed.

---

At this stage the question (to the question's author: @TomDerks) is what to do with the right-most `test1/*` on line 6 ? Should ***all*** its contents be moved to the left-most directory with the same name, which in this case is the first subdir level on the path ? Does "all" includes files in `./test1/test2/test1/` **as well as** the subdirectory `test3` and its contents ?
  The complete solution (Part 2) hinges on that.

Comment: Embedding `{}` in the code argument introduces a command injection vulnerability. See [Is it possible to use \`find -exec sh -c\` safely?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010)

Comment: Note that [echo can't be used to output arbitrary data](/q/65803).

Comment: To split the contents of a variable, if you're going to use the split+glob operator, you'll want to disable globbing. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: tx.

Comment: @CBHihe, thank you for the nice write-up.
Yes all content  should be moved the left most directory. Including all subdirs and their contents. In the end there should only be one test1 directory.

Your suggestion i will try to later today.

Comment: I tried this solution but i does not quite seem to work. Due to lack of knowledge i am not able to correct this command/script.

Comment: @TomDerks: Just run the same script as it is now, that is, as a one liner. It's much less readable but it is completely functional.

Comment: @Cbhihe Thank you, for your answer, i will try it tonight.

Comment: @TomDerks:  Not knowing where you will run it (from what directory), if you have a lot of "Permission denied" type error messages, just run everything with `sudo`. It's goes rather smoothly.   == Part 2 to be completed.